# download file using JSF 2.2 return content-length=0

Tags: eclipse, jsf, io, xhtml, glassfish-4

I'm trying to download file from a JSF page, but when checking the `content-length` in the browser I find it 0.

This is my method in the  managed Bean :

```
  public void downloadFile() throws IOException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        File file = new File("C:\\data\\contacts.doc");
        response.reset();
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=contacts.doc");  
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());  
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();  
        try {  
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file); 
            byte[] buffer =new byte[2048];
           int offset = 0; 
            int byteRead =0;
          while ((offset= input.read(buffer))!= -1 ) {  

               offset += byteRead ;
                out.write(buffer,0,offset);  

           }  
           out.flush();
           out.close();
           input.close();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getResponseComplete();  
        } catch (IOException err) {  
            err.printStackTrace();  
        } finally {  
            try {  
                if (out != null) {  
                    out.close();  
                }  
            } catch (IOException err) {  
                err.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }
```

this is the xhtml page :

```
<h:form>
   <h:commandButton value="Download" action="#{helloBean.downloadFile}" />
</h:form>
```

I'm using Eclispe + Glassfish 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a matter of extension I put .docx instead of .doc( .doc don't exist any more)